# fly scroll bar upper text with CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make a fly scroll bar upper text with CSS or Javascript (without jQuery) like this (in the right)?

[image: scroll-bar example]

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should have given a Google search before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Victor my question is too broad? i asking very spesific thing. and you can be sure that i search in google before

Comment: Your question is too broad because you are basically asking "How to create a scroll-bar with javascript?". Doesn't is sound like a Google search query? You should check the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).